# Twillio Two-Way SMS: How to connect inbound SMS message to the outbound one?

Tags: sms, twilio, webhooks

Inbound SMS messages from Twilio have some details like the from number, etc.

My app is sending out an SMS message to a group of people about an event, and expecting a reply within a short time.

The event of course has an EventId, and I need to connect the reply received to that EventId so that I update the DB with the users who have chosen to reply.

I could store the EventId with all the numbers it was sent to, and then do a lookup based on the "From Number" from Twilio's webhook POST data (the incoming messages)

Then check the time to make sure it's within the "short time" frame I am excepting.

But I am sure there has to be a simpler way?

Like embedding the EventId into the outbound SMS and then receiving it in the inbound SMS?

I have not seen any docs or examples that show this. Is anyone aware of a way to embed the EventId directly into the two-way communication?

Or is the approach I've outlined above pretty much the only thing I can do?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The approach you describe is indeed the best way to approach this.

Joachim mentions the ability to store cookies with SMS messages, but that only applies to incoming messages and you are looking to link to the original outbound message.

Other than that, we would be relying on the third party SMS application on your users' devices to send back data with a message and that is not something that exists.

Your best bet is to look up the `From` number on the incoming message, check out the last message you sent to that number and decide whether this message is related to that one and update the event accordingly.

Comment: thanks Phil! That's exactly what I ended up doing and it's working out pretty well!